# if isset with multiple variables when submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, mysqli

I made this typical form which shows a fade in message when submitting it! It works perfectly with up to 2 variables, but when i'm trying to change my code and insert a third variable or more a problem comes up when submitting.

The html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Basic Form</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A basic fade in form">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<title>Enable Disable Submit Button Based on Validation</title>
<style>
body{width:50%;min-width:200px;font-family:arial;}
#frmDemo {background: #98E6DB;padding: 40px;overflow:auto;}
#btn-submit{padding: 10px 20px;background: #555;border: 0;color: #FFF;display:inline-block;margin-top:20px;cursor: pointer;font-size: medium;}
#btn-submit:focus{outline:none;}
.input-control{padding:10px;width:100%;}
.input-group{margin-top:10px;}
#error_message{
    background: #F3A6A6;
}
#success_message{
    background: #CCF5CC;
}
.ajax_response {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
    color:#555;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery Fade Out Message after Form Submit</h1>          
<form id="frmDemo" action="post-form.php" method="post">


   <div class="input-group">Name </div>
   <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-control" />
   </div>

   <div class="input-group">Message </div>
   <div>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="input-control"></textarea>
   </div>

   <div class="input-group">Lastname </div>
   <div>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="input-control" />
   </div>

   <div style="float:left">
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div id="error_message" class="ajax_response" style="float:left"></div>
    <div id="success_message" class="ajax_response" style="float:left"></div>
</form> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>         
<script>
$("#frmDemo").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();

    if(name == "" || comment == "" || lastname == "" ) {
        $("#error_message").show().html("All Fields are Required");
    } else {
        $("#error_message").html("").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form4.php",
            data: { name:name, comment:comment, lastname:lastname },   // *** Modify this
            success: function(data){
                $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
                }, 2000 );
            }
        });
    }
})
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

and the php code is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "form4";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) { // **Change this

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO step4 (name, comment, lastname) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$comment}' '{$lastname}')";

    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

} else {
    echo "Either Name or Comment field not set";    // **Change this
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I suppose that the problem has to do with some error in my php code in the if isset POST method, because it can handle 2 variables but no more...

Comment: what is the problem? what does the error say?

Comment: what exately happen ? can you dumping $_POST before IF statment and post it ?

Comment: You've missed a comma in your SQL query. Also, you don't seem to sanitize values you include in your SQL queries, which might make your code vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @coderodour! the message says: Error: INSERT INTO step4 (name, comment, lastname) VALUES ('aths', 'as' 'asa') Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

Answer (score 0):

You muss a comma in SQL query - but, if You setup default values in database, it will not throw an error.

I think, the problem is in JSON object in 'data' field in AJAX options.
Try to change syntax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form4.php",
            data: "name="+name+"&comment="+comment+"&lastname="+lastname,
            success: function(data){
                $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
                }, 2000 );
            }
        });
```

Comment: if i use 2 variables in line 14 like so: if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['comment']) everything goes fine! when i add a 3rd variable like: && isset($_POST['lastname']) then the trouble begins...

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax in your query, you forgot about comma:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO step4 (name, comment, lastname) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$comment}' '{$lastname}')";
```

between `'{$comment}' '{$lastname}'`.

Put it there as follows:

`{$comment}', '{$lastname}`

so your code should look as follows:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "form4";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) { // **Change this

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO step4 (name, comment, lastname) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$comment}', '{$lastname}')"; // here the problem occurs

    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

} else {
    echo "Either Name or Comment field not set";    // **Change this
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

In error you can look inside your query:

> Error: INSERT INTO step4 (name, comment, lastname) VALUES ('aths',
>   'as' 'asa') Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

which says your query doesn't have comma between values `as` and `asa`

Comment: you cannot discredit a correct answer for its correctness and then post the same correction as your own answer.

Comment: What? I dont get you, it is a correct answer, there is none else.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the correct anwer! the problem must be in line 14: if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['lastname']))

Comment: Did you change it? Those 3 post are set as `name = 'aths', comment = 'as', lastname = 'asa'`. So they are set, error mean there is problem with SQL syntax.

Comment: yes i tried the change you propose but the same error keeps up :(

Comment: I have updated my answer with whole php code, I bet you dont need those `{}` in query, and it might be: `$sql = "INSERT INTO step4 (name, comment, lastname) VALUES ('$name', '$comment', '$lastname')";`

Comment: thanks again for trying! unfortunatelly the code you propose doesn't work! i think that the problem must be in line 14 instead.

Comment: `isset` should work correctly in your code. Error says that's error in SQL query, not php.